# MySQL running but not responding

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I had a crash on a machine and rebooted and restarted mysql.  Mysql loaded fine, I can connect with 'mysql -p' and do simple commands like "show tables;".  However, real DB operations (e.g., "select [...]") just hang.  Is there any idea on what is going on?

Comment: What is your server load? Is it slow? You can check `top` and `uptime`.

Comment: low.  mysql is running at about 11%.  load average: 2.11, 2.08, 1.99

Comment: That's not *that* low...

Comment: Are any tables showing as locked?  Do your DB ops use locking (e.g., in an app you might be testing)?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -pPASSWORD -A --check
mysqlcheck -u root -pPASSWORD -A --auto-repair
mysqlcheck -u root -pPASSWORD -A --optimize
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL runs check db operations when it boots up, and these make a lock on the dbs.  Try this:

```
show processlist;
```

If a check process is currently running, you'll just have to wait it out.